# bootstrap modal won't show with offline javascript library

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

my bootstrap modal won't show if i use offline "bootstrap.min.js" & "jquery.js"

here the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" scr="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but it can work normaly when i use this online lib :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

what's wrong with that?

thanks,

Comment: i guess your src path is wrong when you are using offline.

Comment: what should i do sir?

Comment: Could you post the picture of the hierarchy of the project. The folder where the HTML file is and the folders where your JS files are. There is probably an issue with the `src` of both scripts

Comment: Show your directory structure ??